# Picasso Library Not Working In RecyclerView in android

Tags: java, android, picasso

So im having this issue in my adapter to were when i go to set the Picasso method to convert my image url it will not allow me to pass the context no matter how i do it. i Have tried this and The class name .this neither seem to work. Not sure what or why this is happening. Here is the adapter class that im having issues with.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ContentViewHolder> {



public  content[] mDataset;

public MyAdapter(content[] data) {
    mDataset = data;

}


@Override
public ContentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
    ContentViewHolder viewHolder = new ContentViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindContent(mDataset[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}

public class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView mUrl;
    public TextView mTitle;
    public TextView mDate;
    public TextView mAuthor;
    public ImageView mThumbnail;

    public ContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mUrl= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.url);
        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        mAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        mThumbnail =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    }

    public void bindContent(content bloginfo) {
        mUrl.setText(bloginfo.getUrl());
        mTitle.setText(bloginfo.getTitle());
        mDate.setText(bloginfo.getDate());
        mAuthor.setText(bloginfo.getAuthor());


        Picasso.with(context).load(bloginfo.getThumbnail()).into(mThumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is `MyAdapter`?. What does it extend

Comment: The my dapter is the name of the class public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ContentViewHolder>

Comment: let me know if you want me to just post the whole class file

Comment: post your adapter class

Comment: What's the version of Picasso in your gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i got this to work here is the working adapter code below. Thank you all for your help.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ContentViewHolder> {

public  content[] mDataset;
private Activity activityContext;

public MyAdapter(Activity context,content[] data) {
    mDataset = data;
    activityContext = context;
}

@Override
public ContentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
    ContentViewHolder viewHolder = new ContentViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindContent(mDataset[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}

public class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView mUrl;
    public TextView mTitle;
    public TextView mDate;
    public TextView mAuthor;
    public ImageView mThumbnail;

    public ContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mUrl= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.url);
        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        mAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        mThumbnail =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    }

    public void bindContent(content bloginfo) {
        mUrl.setText(bloginfo.getUrl());
        mTitle.setText(bloginfo.getTitle());
        mDate.setText(bloginfo.getDate());
        mAuthor.setText(bloginfo.getAuthor());


        Picasso.with(activityContext).load(bloginfo.getThumbnail()).into(mThumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also use `view.getContext()` also

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 Picasso.with(MyAdapter.this)
```

should be

```
 Picasso.with(context)
```

Use Activity Context. This can be passed to the constructor of adapter class from activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Samples available on github

https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/PicassoSampleAdapter.java

Comment: i have tried this as well it does not work either. for some reason its not allowing me to pass either in as a parameter in the reclyer view

Comment: @AlexGwartney then you will need to post bit more code. What you need to pass is a context

Comment: @AlexGwartney i do not see where is context initialized in the first place

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter you can make:

```
private Activity activityContext;
```

then in Adapter contructor:

```
public MyAdapter(Activity context, content[] data) {
    mDataset = data;
    activityContext = context;
}
```

Finally call:

```
Picasso.with(activityContext).load(bloginfo.getThumbnail()).into(mThumbnail);
```

If you create your Adapter in your Activity you need to create it using:
`new myAdapter(this, YOURDATA)`, if you create it in Fragment, you need to use `new myAdapter(getActivity(), YOURDATA)`.

Comment: it does not allow me to pass it in. says method can not be resolved

Comment: I got it to work thanks was not passing it in correctly to my constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.with(mThumbnail.getContext()).load(bloginfo.getThumbnail()).into(mThumbnail);
```